# How to store 15 decimal number as 2 decimal in MongoDB?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb

I need to store **update coverage** for messages in MongoDB.

I'm getting the updated/total messages and then * 100 so I can get the percentage

`total 119 updated 6`

The result will be `5.042016806722689`

**How can I store it as `5.04` ?** Is there any way to store it like that?

`updates_coverage = (updated_event_query / total_event_query) * 100`

The insertion code is:

```
inserted_results_collection.insert_one({"updates_coverage": collection.updates_coverage})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
updates_coverage = round(((updated_event_query / total_event_query) * 100),2)
```